# How to get seconds since unix epoch in Ada?

Tags: calendar, timestamp, ada

I feel very stupid as I don't seem to get a plain Natural number representing the seconds since the unix epoch (01/01/1970 00:00:00) in Ada. I've read the `Ada.Calendar` and it's subpackages up and down but don't seem to find a sensible way of achieving that, even though `Ada.Calendar.Clock` itself is supposed to be exactly what I want...

I am at my wits end. Any nudge in the right direction?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using [`Ada.Calendar.Formatting`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-6-1.html), construct a `Time` representing the [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

```
Epoch : constant Time := Formatting.Time_Of(1970, 1, 1, 0.0);
```

Examine the difference between [`Ada.Calendar.Clock`](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-6.html) and `Epoch`.

```
Put(Natural(Clock - Epoch)'Img);
```

Check the result against this [*epoch display*](http://www.epochconverter.com) or the Unix command `date +%s`.

See [*Rationale for Ada 2005: §7.3 Times and dates*](http://www.adaic.org/resources/add_content/standards/05rat/html/Rat-7-3.html) and [*Rationale for Ada 2012: §6.6 General miscellanea*](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rat/html/Rat12-6-6.html#I1540) for additional details.

Comment: When using standard Ada, type `Natural` may have just 16 bits and GNAT's `'Img` is not defined. This adjustment should work until ca. 2037: `type Secs is range 0 .. 67*365*24*60*60`; also, `Put(Secs'Image(Secs(Clock - Epoch)));`.

Comment: @B98: `Duration'Image` is also likely to be compatible with the implementation defined time base.

Comment: Ada.Calendar.Conversions.To_Ada_Time and To_Unix_Time does it this way, but IIUC incorrectly. As of GNAT 2016 GPL they don't handle leap seconds.

Comment: Also note that fixed point Duration type converts to integral one using Round, and most tools I know expect Floor. Or else you'll be producing timestamps in the future with 1/2 probability.

Answer (score 1):

According to POSIX standard UNIX time does not account leap seconds, while [Ada.Calendar."-" handles them](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-6-1.html#p43):

> For the returned values, if Days = 0, then Seconds + Duration(Leap_Seconds) = Calendar."–" (Left, Right).

One option is to split Ada.Calendar.Time into pieces using Ada.Calendar.Formatting.Split and gather back using POSIX algorithm.

The best option option seems to be to use [Ada.Calendar.Arithmetic.Difference](http://www.ada-auth.org/standards/12rm/html/RM-9-6-1.html#p43). It returns Days, Seconds and Leap_Seconds. You can then combine Days * 86_400 + Seconds to get UNIX time, and Leap_Seconds will be explicitly thrown away as required by POSIX.

I have recently been solving this problem and posted a [library into public domain](https://bitbucket.org/OCTAGRAM/ada-calendar_conversions).

Answer (score 1):

In the GNAT implementation of Ada, there is a private package [`Ada.Calendar.Conversions`](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/ada/libgnat/a-calcon.ads) which contains Ada <-> Unix conversions used by the children of `Calendar`.